# Scite on Ubuntu 22.04 Mate: cannot read text when selected (selection fully black)?

Tags: 22.04, gui, mate, scite

I usually use Scite as my primary text editor, and I just have a new install on Ubuntu 22.04 with Mate desktop, where I noticed the following - when I type text normally, all is good:

[image: scite normal text]

But when I select text with the mouse, both the selection and the text are fully black, and text is in that case unreadable:

[image: scite selected text black]

This I find quite irritating.

By the way, I have this in my User Options file, `~/.SciTEUser.properties`:

```
if PLAT_WINNT
    selection.alpha=32
    selection.back=#000000
if PLAT_GTK
    selection.alpha=60
    selection.back=#000000
selection.multiple=1
selection.additional.fore=#0000AA
selection.additional.back=#880000
selection.additional.alpha=60
```

So apparently the "alpha" of the "selection" does not seem to work anymore (even though it worked for me many Ubuntus the past 10 years).

How can I have the selection to show the text again, as it usually does?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it - the specs for colors changed from hex RGB to hex RGBA ... Just usual change, the usual price of progress - waste of time ...

```yml
# selection colors - too low - going from 30 to 60
if PLAT_WINNT
  # NB: for newer scite (5.2.1 on ubuntu 22.04), this is also RGBA
  selection.alpha=32
  selection.back=#000000
if PLAT_GTK
  ## .alpha seems ignored in ubuntu 22.04/scite 5.2.1 (60 = 0x3C)
  selection.alpha=60
  ## in ubuntu 22.04, selection.back=#444444 as RGB ends up with no alpha at all!
  ##selection.back=#444444
  ## that is because in 22.04, SciTEGlobal properties indicates now these
  ## colors are specified as RGBA, that is, selection.back=#0000001E
  selection.back=#0000003C
  ## in ubuntu 22.04, if .back active as RGB, .fore is ignored (else it works)!
  ##selection.fore=#FF0000
  ## in ubuntu 22.04, there is also: selection.secondary.back=#00800010
selection.multiple=1
# RGBA for scite on ubuntu 22.04 - but just RGB also worksforme:
selection.additional.fore=#0000AA
##selection.additional.back=#880000
##selection.additional.alpha=60
# RGBA for scite on ubuntu 22.04:
selection.additional.back=#0000003C
```

Now it looks good as it used to:

[image: scite-ok-again]